# Move Kitchen to Living Room-Unit

Tags: electrical, plumbing, kitchens

My unit is on the ground floor, I am thinking to combine kitchen and living room to create an open kitchen and renovate original kitchen to a bathroom/Laundry. I know it sounds crazy and probably insanely costly, just curious if it is possible?
 In terms of plumbing/electrical works, what should I do to make sure it is doable?

Below is the floor plan:

[image: Floor plan]

Comment: What is underneath your unit?  It seems that all of your plumbing is on the bottom wall.  It would be heavily dependent on the amount of access you have.

Comment: 1. Floor plan not attached (I can't see anything below Your last line ("Below is the floor plan:"). 2. It may be wise to post country Your unit is located, as codes may differ between countries. 3. I believe that it may be doable, details will matter here.